# I would like to know what the m means in this MUI styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles

This is a `sx` property of one of my MUI components.
What does `m:1` means here?

```
sx={{
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  '& > :not(style)': {
    m: 1,
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
  },
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`m` is the abbreviation of `margin`.
And `mt`, `mr`, `mb`, `ml` mean `margin-top`, `margin-right`, `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` respectively.
Swap the `m` with `p` and you will have `padding` properties just with this pattern.
See the full list and usage examples [here](https://mui.com/system/spacing/).